# How to loop cells based on value if some equal #N/A in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro that includes looping through some cells, continuing until the cell is empty (value = ""). However, some of the cells have a "value" of #N/A... I want to use this as a marker to delete any rows where this is the case, however, in checking that the cell's value is or isn't empty, the loop will come across many cells that are equal to #N/A. This causes an error because I guess this isn't really a value, but rather an indication that a command run (in this case, Vlookup) returned that it didn't work for that cell? The error given is a type mismatch. How do I get around this... ie. how can I have the loop still check the cell's value despite #N/A not really being a value?

Comment: use `if Iserror(cells( i,j )) then Rows(i).EntirerRow.Delete` loop it from last to first row when you delete.

Comment: The amount and position of cells to check is variable upon each iteration of the macro though... so how do I set the loop? I figured the until = "" would be good, but since it is a type mismatch, I am not sure how to loop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all the find all the cells with a **#N/A** and delete the cells row.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithErrors()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Range
    With Worksheets(1).Cells

        Do
            Set c = .Find(What:="#N/A", _
            After:=.Range("A1"), _
            Lookat:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                .Rows(c.Row).Delete

            End If
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```